# jQuery .wrap() - specify position to wrap around

Tags: jquery

Can i use jQuery's .wrap() to do the following (and if so - how?)

**Originally:**

```
<span class="foo"></span>
```

**What i need:**

```
<div class="container">
    <ul></ul>
    <span class="foo"></span>
</div>
```

**What happens now:**

```
 <div class="container">
    <ul>
        <span class="foo"></span>
    </ul>
 </div>
```

*using this:*

```
$('.foo').wrap('<div class="container"><ul></ul></div>');
```

Whats the most impressive way get this working? Is .wrap() the wrong way?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually `.wrap()` will not work as you are expecting, you need to `prepend` the `ul` after wrapping the `.foo` with `.container` in order to accomplish your task.

Try,

```
$('.foo').wrap('<div class="container"></div>')
           .closest('.container')
             .prepend('<ul></ul>');
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
$('.foo').wrap('<div class="container"></div>').parent().prepend('<ul></ul>');
```

**[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ZBM2m/)**

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('.foo').wrap('<div class="container"></div>').closest('.container').prepend('<ul></ul>');
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/RM9Be/5/)**